# How to make Emacs operation safe without hanging or crashing the whole editor

Tags: emacs

In my understanding, an operation should really not hang the editor. I can at most accept the fact that this operation is not successful, but what I encountered is that I frequently crash my emacs instance.

- opening a remote file => hang!
- syncing a shell buffer PWD => hang！

Is this really the case, or are there some configuration options we can make use of to to avoid the hangs?

I will add the steps I used to produce the crash: my emacs versin ( GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.22.1) )

1. `C-x C-f` (some remote file) /user@host:/var/tmp/a.txt ( never
   succeeded )
2. several change directory (under M-x shell ), and then M-x dirs (
   frequently stuck )

I have to admit that `C-g` works to stop these stuck operations sometimes.

Comment: Emacs is one of the least crashable programs ever.
And it doesn't hang in my experience, just tries to execute the commands that I give to it.
If I don't want to wait for execution to finish, `C-g` always works.
I've had maybe 2-3 crashes over the last year, all of them on account of Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @abo-abo Majority of the ones I have experienced were because of network activity. E.g. when ido-mode is enabled the path is at `\\foo\bar` and one types in a file/dirname (something like what OP pointed out) which doesn't exist in the current path and ido goes down hunting for it. `C-g` doesn't work in that situation, Emacs gets dead frozen and the only cure I found was to disable and enable the network adapter to save my Emacs session plus time.

Comment: in fact C-g works, haven't used this for sometime. thanks.

Comment: This would really depend on whether you use vanilla Emacs, or have you added some more code. Not to say that Emacs can't crash or hang, but what you describe isn't crashing (crash happens when application closes unexpectedly). If you want to be super careful about not hanging (typically when writing your eLisp code, not when using interactive commands), you'd call it from `with-timeout` or `with-local-quit` to ensure that the operation will either terminate on its own or that the user will be able to terminate it.

Comment: With something like this, whether it is an Emacs bug or perhaps an enhancement request for Emacs, you really need to provide a helpful recipe to reproduce the hang, preferably starting from `emacs -Q`. Otherwise, you are essentially just saying that Emacs sometimes hangs when you try to access stuff remotely -- not helpful enough to do anything about the problem. I have no doubt that you've run into real problems, so please try to give a recipe to `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also thought Emacs should be one of the most robust editors in the world, but the truth is it crashes. Sometimes it hangs... maybe it is a result that I am using a lot of unnecessary plugins. Use `C-g` to unhang it.

Comment: Why not try using a recent release of Emacs? You're not *horribly* out of date, but 23.3 is a couple of years old at this point, and if Emacs is actually crashing on you it would seem sensible to try out a newer version.

Comment: the reason I don't do that is I thought newest versions are frequently not reliable compared with stable ones. the one I have in house, 24.1/24.3 seems not a stable release though. but good point perhaps need to update it now.